# Sorting Y-Axis Values ascendingly in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get this plot out of my data

[image]

and I am trying to have the points sorted descendingly (fist = highest; last = lowest).I tried reorder as well as mutate with my code but with no success.

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Team, y = Days)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(Country))) + facet_wrap( ~ Country, ncol = 2)
```

The data files (xls) looks  like this:

```
Country Team    Days
England Arsenal FC  1.495
England Aston Villa 851
England Brighton & Hove Albion  1.125
England Burnley FC  1.181
England Chelsea FC  1.061
England Crystal Palace  781
England Everton FC  1.275
Frankreich  AS Monaco   714
Frankreich  AS Saint-Étienne    859
Frankreich  Angers SCO  809
Frankreich  Dijon FCO   938
Frankreich  FC Lorient  1.071
Frankreich  FC Metz 717
Frankreich  FC Nantes   856
```

Any idea how to code this?
Thx!

Comment: Provide `my_data` in `dput()` format. Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Without your data, it's hard to know for sure if this will work, but a simple thing to try is `scale_y_reverse()`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with this little twist

```
geom_point(aes(reorder(Team, Days, mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

library(tidyverse)

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~Team,    ~Days,
  'England', 'Arsenal FC',  1495,
  'England', 'Aston Villa', 851,
  'England', 'Brighton & Hove Albion',  1125,
  'Frankreich',  'AS Monaco',   714,
  'Frankreich',  'AS Saint-Étienne',    859,
  'Frankreich',  'Angers SCO',  809
)


ggplot(df,aes(Days,reorder(Team,Days),color = Team)) + 
  geom_point()

ggplot(df,aes(Days,reorder(Team,-Days),color = Team)) + 
  geom_point()

# I would go with geom_col
ggplot(df,aes(Days,reorder(Team,Days),fill = Country)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  labs(y = '')
```

[image]